# Can someone help me with a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I need help with writing a regular expression for the following rules:

1. White spaces aren't allowed.
2. The only case where white spaces are allowed is inside brackets `[]`.

I have came up with this expression:

```
[^(\\[\s\\])]
```

But in this case each of the chars: `[`, white space, and `]` is not allowed separately.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression like:

```
^(?:[^][\s]|\[[^]]*\])*\z
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. Here's one  :

```
^([^\s\[]*(\[[^\]]*)*)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\S|\[.*?])*$
```

- `\S` not whitespace
- `|` or
- `\[.*?]` any characters inside brackets